# Rake Time Zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

How would I add a new time zone to the list of time zones?

If I would have to simply add a time zone to my system, why doesn't it appear on the list:

```
rake time:zones:all
```

As mentioned by ranja below, I tried to use ActiveSupport with time zones.

So I open up the console

```
user@host:/var/www/project$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_support'
=> true
irb(main):002:0>
```

But what should I use next? And will the new time zone be lost?
How would I implement a permanent new ruby time zone which would be available on all my aps? Thanks so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your rails console type below command , you can get list of name

```
     ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this in application.rb for rails 3.X and enviroment.rb in rails 2.x

`config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`

after that do

`rake time:zones:all`

Thanks

Comment: Hello Raja, the question was not how to configure a timezone. I would like to add a completely new time zone to the list of available time zones.

Comment: Hope you got your answer over here http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Or http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-create  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.create

Comment: Hello Raja, I updated my question. Thanks for the links, but I'm not experienced enough. Please respond with a new answer - your current answer is not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: @Peter: I wish I didn't got your query. Could you please tell me which time zone you are not getting form `ActiveSupport`.

Comment: Hello Rony, how to get a list of time zones with `ActiveSupport`? I could not get it to work with the ruby console