# rake time:zones:all not listing anything on Terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm on Terminal trying to use `rake time:zones:all` to list all Time Zones and I get the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Help is appreciated for obtaining a list of all Time Zones. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rake Time Zones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081491/rake-time-zones)

Comment: Not a duplicate question. When I type rake time:zones:all I don't get a list of Time Zones and instead I get the error message above. I'm not trying to add a new Time Zone I'm trying to see the list of Time Zones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are just outside of your application's root directory. Make sure you are running the command from the right place:

```
cd
cd path/to/your/app
```